# Open Layer drag marker without mapview dragging

Tags: openlayers

Hello guys I am using openlayers map in my project and I want to drag marker without mapview dragging but I could not do that with angular.

```
const attribution = new Attribution({
    collapsible: false,
});

this.map = new Map({
    target: "map",

    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM({}),
        }),
        new VektorLayer({
            updateWhileAnimating: true,
            source: new Vector({
                features: [
                    new Feature({
                        geometry: new 
                        Point(fromLonLat([
                            Number(this.longitude), 
                            Number(this.latitude)
                        ]))
                    })
                ],
            }),

            style: new Style({
                image: new Icon({
                    anchor: [0.5, 46],
                    anchorXUnits: IconAnchorUnits.FRACTION,
                    anchorYUnits: IconAnchorUnits.PIXELS,
                    src: "//raw.githubusercontent.com/jonataswalker/map 
                         utils/master/images/marker.png",
                }),
            }),
        });
    ],
    
    view: new View({

        center: fromLonLat([
            Number(this.longitude),
            Number(this.latitude),
        ]),
        zoom: 15,
        showFullExtent: true
    }),
    
    controls: defaultControls({ attribution: false }).extend([attribution, ]),

    });
});
```

Comment: You would need to add a Modify interaction or a Translate interaction.  For example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/modify-icon.html

Comment: Thanks dude for your help.